# How to center a slick slider full width?

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I'm trying to build a special fullwidth carousel with slick(centerMode) : http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/.

My problem is that the image are floated Left when i wanted to see all the slider and all the image on my fullwidth without any float.
Like the picture 
Thanks
[image: This how i want the slider]

I have already implement the slider : check by screen>2000px you will understand what i mean .
https://jsfiddle.net/voldemort95/69ucj3zt/9/

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  autoplaySpeed: 550,
  rtl: false,
  slidesToScroll: 2,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  infinite: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  touchMove: true,
});
function slickPause() {
    $('.slider').slick('slickPause');
}
slickPause();
$('.slider').mouseover(function() {
    $('.slider').slick('slickPlay')
});
$('.slider').mouseout(function() {
    slickPause();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

[class="slick-active"] {
       background: black;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 60px;
   background-color: #230e2c;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slick-activeafter{
  background: red
}
.item.slick-slide.slick-center + .slick-slide {
transform:"";
    /* z-index: 10; */
}
.wrap:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 200;
  padding: 0 0px;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 5rem;
  z-index: 300;
  outline: none;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: -50px;
  text-align: left;
}

.slick-next {
  right: -50px;
  text-align: right;
}

.item.slick-slide {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px !important;
  transition: transform .4s;
  position: relative;
}

.slick-slide:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: solid 1px #979797;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.11);
  transition: transform .4s;
}

.item.slick-slide {
  transform: scale(0.7)  translate(640px);
}

.slick-slide.slick-current {
    opacity: 1;
}
.item.slick-slide.slick-center + .slick-slide {
  transform: scale(0.8) translate(-250px);
  z-index: 10;
}

.item.slick-slide.slick-center + .slick-slide + .item.slick-slide {
  transform: scale(0.7)  translate(-640px);
  z-index: 5;
}

.item.slick-slide.slick-active {
  transform: scale(0.8) translate(250px);
}

.item.slick-slide.slick-center {
  /* margin: 0 -10%; */
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 30;
}
.slick-center{
  border: solid 1px #979797;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #d9d9d9);
}

.slick-center .description{
  display: inline-block;
  color : #5b1f74;
}

.slick-center .title{
  color : #5b1f74;
  font-size: 40px;

}

.slick-center .img{
  display: inline-block;
}
.slick-slide img {
     display: none;
}
p.title{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  left: 37%;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 50%;
}
p.description{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="slider">

    <div class="item">
      <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
      <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
    <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
      <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
      <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
      <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
      <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
      <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
      <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
      <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
      <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
      <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
      <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
    <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
      <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <img src=".." class="img" style=" width: 97px;height: 155px;    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;" alt="">
      <p class="title">TEST</p>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an awesome use of Slick; I am a fan. However I don't think you can do this using CSS (since you can't pick specifically the next sibling or the last sibling). You'll need to write up some JS using a Slick Event like `setPosition` that resets the `transform` on the last and next slides
I'll try to write something up when I get the chance but may be this will get you on the right track?

Comment: I have tried that using JavaScript, I'll try more, thanks

Comment: I've done something similar in the past so I'll post some sample code when I get a chance this afternoon; good luck in the meantime!

Comment: Thanks I am trying this slick function like you said on('FUNCTION', function(event, slick, currentSlide,..){

Comment: I have try it to do it with JS but no chance :/ do you have any idea ?

Comment: Here is something that works when moving forward one slide: https://jsfiddle.net/vyocsfup/

We'd need to get it working for moving backward as well but it's a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to my comment above, this will work going forward and backward by 1 slide: https://jsfiddle.net/08vLok1w/

It could be refactored to minimize some of the jQuery calls and it will break if you jump multiple slides at once but that's something that could also be built in to this (would need to keep track of `nextSlide` and `currentSlide` outside the scope of the `beforeChange` method).

Your HTML should be untouched, but below you will find the updated JS:

```
$('.slider').on('init', function(event, slick){
    jQuery(".slider .slick-slide.slick-active.slick-center").next().next().next().css("transform", "scale(0.7)  translate(-640px)");
    jQuery(".slider .slick-slide.slick-active.slick-center").next().next().next().next().css("transform", "scale(0.7)  translate(-640px)");
});

$('.slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    rtl: false,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    arrows: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    touchMove: true,
    draggable: false
});
function slickPause() {
    $('.slider').slick('slickPause');
}
slickPause();
$('.slider').mouseover(function() {
    $('.slider').slick('slickPlay')
});
$('.slider').mouseout(function() {
    slickPause();
});

$('.slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    if(nextSlide == currentSlide) { return false; }
    if(nextSlide - currentSlide == 1 || nextSlide - currentSlide < -1) {
        var slide1 = jQuery(`.slick-slide[data-slick-index=${nextSlide + 3}]`);
        var slide2 = jQuery(`.slick-slide[data-slick-index=${nextSlide + 4}]`);

        jQuery(".slider .slick-slide").css("transform", "");
        jQuery(".slider .slick-slide.slick-active.slick-center").prev().css("transform", "scale(0.7)  translate(640px)")
        jQuery(".slider .slick-slide.slick-active.slick-center").css("transform", "scale(0.8) translate(250px)");
        jQuery(".slider .slick-slide.slick-active").not(".slick-center").eq(1).css("transform", "scale(1)");
        jQuery(".slider .slick-slide.slick-active").not(".slick-center").eq(1).next().css("transform", "scale(0.8) translate(-250px)");
        jQuery(slide1).css("transform", "scale(0.7)  translate(-640px)");
        jQuery(slide2).css("transform", "scale(0.7)  translate(-640px)");
        console.log("next")
    } else {
        var slide1 = jQuery(`.slick-slide[data-slick-index=${currentSlide + 2}]`);
        var slide2 = jQuery(`.slick-slide[data-slick-index=${currentSlide + 3}]`);

        jQuery(".slider .slick-slide").css("transform", "");
        jQuery(".slider .slick-slide.slick-active.slick-center").next().css("transform", "scale(0.7)  translate(-640px)")
        jQuery(".slider .slick-slide.slick-active.slick-center").css("transform", "scale(0.8) translate(-250px)");
        jQuery(".slider .slick-slide.slick-active").not(".slick-center").eq(0).css("transform", "scale(1)");
        jQuery(".slider .slick-slide.slick-active").not(".slick-center").eq(0).prev().css("transform", "scale(0.8) translate(250px)");
        jQuery(slide1).css("transform", "scale(0.7)  translate(-640px)");
        jQuery(slide2).css("transform", "scale(0.7)  translate(-640px)");
        console.log("prev")
    }
});
```

And Added CSS:

```
.slick-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(50% - 200px);
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: none;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 5rem;
    z-index: 300;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Great job, i really appreciate what you did I have tried your code, the problem that I face now, that the slider before I make the change will have that problem, I have tried to use ### on('init', function())## I will update my answer if I solved. Do you have any idea ?  Thank you again

Comment: I'm confused, do you mean the slides on the right are not in position when you init? If that is the case, I could add something in that would address that. 

PS: I'll probably continue tinkering with this as I might want to use it later (assuming that's okay) and if I create something better I'll be sure to update this ticket

Comment: Exactly the slides on the right are not in position on init. I have tried it with init Function also but not working, great thank you again.

Comment: I want to reduce the amount of jQuery calls to make this a bit more efficient, but I added the `onInit` function to place that next slide. This should get you started so let me know what you think.

Comment: I see that it work fine till now thank you for the effort,one problem if you notice is if you try to select directly the second or the third slider from the right side , all the slider will have a problem and all the slider will transform

Comment: Yea, that was something I mentioned, that you would only be able to move forward/backward one slide at a time. You could get around that by adding hidden arrows (opacity: 0.1 or 0) that cover everything but the middle 3 slides or you could keep track of `currentSlide` and add another conditional for when current slide moves more than 1. These are the improvements I was alluding to but can't add right now. I would like to keep working on it but these bits will take some time

Comment: I am working on it now, trying to do that I have made some change I will update my post if anything change :D thanks

Comment: I give up on it

Comment: I've added a slight update so the answer should now be a little better

Comment: I see that it's so much better (perfect), actually it works good, thank you for your work and your effort, i really appreciate that  :D